Suspicious function for calculating cardinality via $\ell_0$ norm
I'm confused about a function for calculating a vector's cardinality via the $\ell_0$ norm as described in an "Optimization Models" textbook (ISBN: 9781107050877). Here's a photo of that page of the textbook. The card(x) function in the margin is:
$$\text{card}(x) = \|x\|_{0} = \lim_{p \to 0} \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_{k}|^p \right)^{1/p}$$
When I apply an example vector x = (3,4,0) to this card(x) function. I expect to get a result of 2, but I believe it approaches infinity instead.
Am I doing something wrong here, or is there an error in the textbook?

Yes, that's an error in the textbook. One correct statement is that
$$ \operatorname{card}(x) = \lim_{p \to 0^+} \sum_{k=1}^n |x_k|^p $$
(note the lack of $1/p$ exponent).
In general, the $\|{\cdot}\|_p$ as defined in your book is only actually a norm for $p \ge 1$; for $0 < p < 1$ it fails the triangle inequality. Removing the $1/p$ exponent gives you something else that satisfies the triangle inequality for $p < 1$, but then is no longer homogeneous (the third property in your definition of norm).

Yes, you are right. The textbook is wrong. With the current form of the expression, the limit equals$\infty$.
Instead, let us look at the limit of the $\log$ of that expression. $$ \lim_{p \to 0} \log \left[ \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_{k}|^p \right)^{1/p} \right] \ = \ \lim_{p \to 0} \dfrac {\log \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n} |x_{k}|^p \right)} p $$
As $p$ approaches $0$, the numerator is bounded between $0$ and $n$, whereas the denominator approaches $0$. Therefore, the limit is $\boxed\infty$.
P.S: In the other answer, arkeet clarifies how the norm should be defined in order to give the cardinality.
